# Transformation to NSStringFromCGAffineTransform

Tags: iphone, transformation

I am trying to save a transformed (rotated, scaled and moved) `UIImageView` and load the transformations back to the screen but it doesn't work at all. Every time i try, the `UIImageView` is on a different place as it should be.

Here some code:

Saving into `UserDefaults`:

```
NSUserDefaults * UserDefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
UIImageView * petit = (UIImageView*)[ConView viewWithTag:1];
[UserDefs setBool:YES forKey:@"gespeichert"];
[UserDefs setObject:NSStringFromCGRect([petit frame]) forKey:@"frame"];
[UserDefs setObject:NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(petit.transform) forKey:@"position1"];
[UserDefs synchronize];
```

Loading from UserDefaults:

```
CGAffineTransform transformation = CGAffineTransformFromString([UserDefs objectForKey:@"position1"]);
    su.transform = transformation; // "su" is an UIImageView - allocated with Frame from:
    CGRect RectFrame = CGRectFromString([UserDefs objectForKey:@"frame"]);
```

What did i wrong ?
Maybe some one can help me.

## # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

Edit:
I changed the code now:
For loading

```
CGRect frameGroesse;
    frameGroesse = CGRectFromString([UserDefs objectForKey:@"frame"]);
    UIImageView * su = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frameGroesse];
    su.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Xcode.jpg"];
    su.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    su.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    su.tag = 1;
    [su setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:su];
    CGAffineTransform transformation = CGAffineTransformFromString([UserDefs objectForKey:@"position1"]);
    su.transform = transformation;
    su.center = CGPointFromString([UserDefs objectForKey:@"center"]);

    [ConView addSubview:su];
    [ConView bringSubviewToFront:su];
    [ConView bringSubviewToFront:[ConView viewWithTag:1]];
    [su release];
```

For saving:

```
NSUserDefaults * UserDefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
UIImageView * petit = (UIImageView*)[ConView viewWithTag:1];
[UserDefs setBool:YES forKey:@"gespeichert"];
[UserDefs setObject:NSStringFromCGRect([petit bounds]) forKey:@"frame"];
[UserDefs setObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(petit.center) forKey:@"center"];

[UserDefs setObject:NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(petit.transform) forKey:@"position1"];
[UserDefs synchronize];
```

But after loading the image, i still get a small movement. Still need some assistance please.

Answer (score 0):

The CGAffineTransform may invalid the frame property of the view you apply the transform, so maybe you are not storing a usefull frame...

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix `transform`, `bounds`, and `center` with `frame`. For example, setting `transform` to a view will affect its frame. As for your `UIImageView`: its position in superview should be defined by its `center`. Its rotation/scale should be defined by `transform` (don't put translations in transform for simplicity). The size should be defined by `bounds.size`. So, you have to store three items.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. i changed my code to bounds and added the center. But still not got the result i wish. You may have a small example please ?

Comment: Sure, but first explain what is "the result i wish". Write down your code, numbers you log, numbers you expect, etc.

Comment: After restarting the app i need to re-display the imageview at exactly the same point it was saved. Right now at every loading the image is a few pixels (sometimes more, sometimes less) away from where it should be. The positions in the logs looks good - but the view is still moved away from the point it was at saving. I dropped the Code here [link](http://snipt.org/lgHo9) . Thanks for your answer. Edit: It may have something to do with the GestureRecognizer ? Theoretical everything should work fine...

Comment: Looks alright. (You do not have to use that `frame` at all.) Now you are saying that values read from user defaults are the same as values written to user defaults. I would add more logging to check at which point those values change. Those gestures: are you using them? If not - remove them from code... The idea is to isolate the problem... Good luck.